# Поиск файлов в каталоге

Tags: php

Есть скипт php который считывает название файлов в папке (название транслит латиницей) и переводит их на русский. Как сделать поиск по папке с учетом что искать будут на русском?

Для наглядности код:

```
<?php  
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {  
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {  
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {  
            $files[] = $file;  
        }  
    }  
    closedir($handle);  
}  
/* config */  
$COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE = 37;  
###  
$COUNT_FIELES = count($files);  
$COUNT_PAGES = intval($COUNT_FIELES / $COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE);  
if(empty($_GET['p']) || $_GET['p'] < 0 || $_GET['p'] > $COUNT_PAGES || !intval($_GET['p']))  
$_GET['p'] = 0;

echo '<h2>Файлов с табулатурами: '.$COUNT_FIELES.'</h2>';  
echo 'Всего страниц с файлами: <b>'.($COUNT_PAGES +1).'</b><br>';  
echo 'Файлов на страницу: <b>'.$COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE.'</b><br>';;  
echo 'Текущая страница: <b>'.($_GET['p']+1).'</b><br>';  
echo '<br><center><strong>Если закачка не началась вставте ссылку в свой менеджер закачек (Download Master)</strong></center><br>';

for ($i=0; $i<= $COUNT_PAGES;$i++) {  
echo '<a href="?p='.$i.'">['.($i+1).']</a> '; 
}  
echo '<hr>';

$START = $_GET['p'] * $COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE;  
$END = $START + $COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE;

for ($i = $START; $i < $END; $i++) {

if(key_exists($i,$files)) {  
if(is_file('.'.$files[$i]))

$cat = "$files[$i]";  //строка, подлежащая частичной замене
$r=array("yo","ye","ts","ch","sh","shch","yu","ya","a","b","v","g","d","e","j","z","i","y","k","l","m","n","o","p","r","s","t","u","f","e","_","h","w");           // Что менять "a" ?b");
$r2=array("ё","ё","ц","ч","ш","щ","ю","я","а","б","в","г","д","е","г","з","и","и","к","л","м","н","о","п","р","с","т","у","ф","э"," ","х","в");          // На что менять "0" ?1");
$trans = str_ireplace($r,$r2,$cat);

echo '<img src="/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href="/gitara/tabs_ru/'.$cat.'" title="'.$trans.' скачать файл">Файл: '.$trans.'</a><br>';

if(is_dir('.'.$files[$i]))
echo $files[$i].' - [DIR]<br>';  
}       
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать запрос на русском обратно перевести в транслит латиницы и уже его использовать в качестве запроса по которому искать. Соответствие символов у Вас есть уже, просто нужно обратно перевести их с русского на латиницу.

Comment: Это я и сам знаю. Лучше скажи как это сделать?